# Model has a hole in it due to weird geometry in wireframe mode?

Tags: modeling, mesh, wireframe

I'm fairly new to blender and have encountered a problem with wireframe mode. The screenshots show a hole that is visible in object mode but not in edit mode. I turned on wireframe mode to see the geometry and as you can see from the images it looks strange in this area. Any ideas how to get my mesh looking normal?
Screenshots-
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Blend file- [image]

Apologies if the answer is obvious, i've been trying to figure it out myself but have got nowhere. I've tried:
-Deleting loose vertices
-Merging by distance (removing double vertices)
-seeing if any ngons or tris in the area (there are none)
-Moving the vertices in the area around (nothing changes)
-Googling wireframe mode to learn about this mode and how geometry is generated because If I knew how it generated the geometry maybe i could fix it (couldn't really find much relevant info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a shapekey and it is selected, so whenever you try to bring some corrections in *Edit* mode it changes this shapekey, not the base shapekey, and as soon as you come back to *Object* mode, you don't see what you've done on this second shapekey, as its value is at 0, you only see the base shapekey, which remains unchanged. So you need to select the base shapekey and work on it, you can even delete this second shapekey if it's not useful.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was following a tutorial and didn't realise this problem was anything to do with the shape keys-thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me, but I'm not able to reproduce it right now.

These vertices are not perfectly on the axis, so the mirroring is duplicating them over very close to the axis.

An interaction with subdivision surface is creating this pinch.

You should be able to select the problem verts and use the N panel to set their positions exactly to the axis and eliminate this extra geometry.  You may then have to run a merge operation depending on what exactly is happening.

[image]